# readline() in php not taking all the entries

Tags: php, readline

I have an issue with readline() skipping some of the entries . It is done simple in the example below.

```
<?php

while(readline()!="stop")
{
    echo "You have entered:". readline()."\n"; 
}
```

It gives me

```
1
2
You have entered:2
2
2
You have entered:2
3
3
You have entered:3
t
t
You have entered:t
5

You have entered:
5
5
You have entered:5
stop
Done.
```

The stop is read from the first time , the rest need to me entered twice. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In your echo, you are calling `readline()` again, you need to store the first value and just output it in the echo...

```
while(($text = readline())!="stop")
{
    echo "You have entered:". $text."\n"; 
}
```